# authentication redirect with offline webapp (gae python, html5)

Tags: google-app-engine, html, authentication, caching

To GAE+html5 gurus out there :)

When user logs on to a GAE hosted application, his credentials are stored locally in a cookie (correct?).

After this cookie expires (e.g. if users hits **logout** on another browser tab), no **login_required** protected methods will work.

Regular webapp will require re-authentication next time the user navigates to a **login_protected** url by  automatically redirecting to a login screen.

What would be the right way for a cached webapp to be handling this?

My test is a simple **login_protected** page accessed by Chrome and iOS browser. It's cached and accessible offline as expected. Then, (while online) and after the authentication expires, the server log shows a 302 response which is followed by 200 response of the authentication dialog page, but of course no authentication happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google authentication to provide access to your page . Which means even if you are logged in one of the other google services. Your cookie still exists in the browser. login_required will assume that you are logged on based on the cookie. What you are seeing is a redirection to google's page that's 302. If you want you can manage sessions on your own and check for authentication based on your data in data Store.There are lot of solutions availble for both Python and Java .

Comment: Actually, (in my iOS setup) it seems cookies are NOT shared between my (cached, full-screen) webapp and the browser.

Comment: Any of these session management solutions support free secure authentication? :-) Can you point to one or two? Thanks!

Comment: @Sergey, you are using python or java?

Comment: @Abdul, python on server, javascript on (html5 cached) client, regular google accounts for authentication.

Comment: @Sergey have a look at the gae sessions here https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions

Comment: @Abdul - thanks! This seems like a useful library. For now, I think I'll settle with a simpler approach: once I detect the user has been logged out (and provided he actually **needs** some protected data), I'll just redirect the browser to the login url.